# When, if ever, is eisegesis a valid interpretation of scripture over exegesis?

Tags: exegesis

Typically, [exegesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exegesis) is used when interpreting scripture, so that value, meaning, and instruction is derived *from* the words.

When is [eisegesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisegesis), or reading-into scripture, a valid interpretational technique?

Comment: Isn't this asking "when is it right to misinterpret scripture"?

Comment: My first thought was, "When you are more interested in making a point than in discovering the truth..."

Comment: Unfortunately this is too subjective (opinion-based) and broad for this format, but [here is an entire book that proposes an answer to this question](http://a.co/hZN3TV3) that you may enjoy.

Comment: @Dan - I disagree on its opinion-based-ness in this format, as you can see below: given there are upvoted answers (including, of course, the *accepted* answer)

Comment: Unfortunately @warren - as no specific Christian perspective is requested, different Christian groups will reasonably disagree on this question and thus I still believe it is opinion-based for this site.

Comment: @Dan - I understand you think it's bad subjective. I disagree with you, as did those who answered it. This is a pretty clear question that shouldn't demand a specific "Christian perspective".

Comment: I'm really surprised that as seasoned an SE user as you would say that the existence of upvoted answers demonstrates that the question is not a "bad subjective" question. Further, the question is at a net negative downvotes and the top answer says it "seems like an odd question"; both of these facts point in the direction of readers not finding it a terribly useful question. For this question to avoid the opinion-based trap, it might be useful to ask something like, "Do any groups claim that eisegesis is ever superior to exegesis?"

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude - I'm surprised a question which did fine for 4.5 years would suddenly be deemed "bad". The. What I've votes all happened recently, and the question has good answers (including the accepted one). Narnian answered this quite well when it was asked. Feel free to disagree, but this has been fine for years - and the sudden change in mood is somewhat baffling.

Comment: Warren, standards on this site have been shifting for quite some time –  there are hundreds of questions from 2011 and 2012 that were only closed in 2015 or later.   Because there are so many "Christian" groups that disagree with each other on practically everything, questions asking for the "truth" rather than a particular group's view are likely to be closed when they are noticed.  If you don't agree with that assessment, and the reopen effort fails, I'd encourage you to post about this on meta if you'd like further review.

Comment: I find it a bit annoying too, basically, if someone is gonna close my old questions, I'd rather not even know about it.   So @Dan unless there's a good reason to propose that someone actually edit a question, I wouldn't bother letting 'em know why you're closing the question.  4.5 years later, it's just annoying to see your question is being closed.

Comment: @PeterTurner the primary reason I commented was to post (at least what I felt was) a helpful reading recommendation for the OP that answers this question in depth, proposing that there should be *more* eisegetical readings of Scripture (or rather, everyone's reading is already eisegetical but we're all in denial -- thank you literary theorists). I also pointed out the reason for my close vote.

Comment: @Nathaniel - I agree with Peter Turner here. Standards may change: but retroactively applying new standards to old things doesn't do much to encourage long-time users. If anything, it discourages them. Close and disallow voting: indicating that new standards exist and this is now an example of a question that shouldn't be asked? Perhaps. SO has done precisely that - without (seemingly) scaring-off too many people.

Comment: @warren, we're chatting a bit about this post in case you're interested. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like an odd question.  The only answer that seems reasonable would be that **you read into Scripture the meaning you want it to have when you disagree with the actual meaning.**

To read into Scripture what is not there is to put oneself as somehow over Scripture as more of an authority on the matter than the Scriptures themselves.  There are definitely two distinct approaches to the Scriptures.

*Two people will see in the Scriptures something that differs from either their own ideas or their own deeds.  One person will conclude, **The Bible** must be wrong, and then misinterprets it to make it agree with him.  Another will conclude, **I** must be wrong, and changes his ideas or his life to agree with the Bible.*

I would argue that only one of these is a true follower of Jesus and of His teachings.  Eisegesis is *never* appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

The answer would depend on who you were asking. One man's "eisegesis" is another man's "orthodoxy," and it's not altogether uncommon to hear the former term levied as an accusation against any that disagree with a speaker's stance on any particular theological issue.

The Westminster Confession of Faith, which many Christians believe to be entirely consonant with Scripture, is one example of a document that seems, in articles 1.9 and 1.10,  to state a very clear position wholly against eisegesis, in favor of a *Sola Scriptura*-style "interpret-the-Scriptures-by-the-Scriptures" exegetical approach.

> [*WCF, Chapter 1*](http://reformed.org/documents/wcf_with_proofs/index.html):
>
> IX. The infallible rule of interpretation of Scripture is the Scripture itself: and therefore, when there is a question about the true and full sense of any Scripture (which is not manifold, but one), it must be searched and known by other places that speak more clearly.
>
> X. The supreme judge by which all controversies of religion are to be determined, and all decrees of councils, opinions of ancient writers, doctrines of men, and private spirits, are to be examined, and in whose sentence we are to rest, can be no other but the Holy Spirit speaking in the Scripture.

Answer (score 3):

Peter says pretty clearly that that's not ever a good idea:

> [2 Peter 1:20-21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Peter%201:20-21)
>
> 20 Knowing this first, that no prophecy of the scripture is of any
>   private interpretation.
>
> 21 For the prophecy came not in old time by the will of man: but holy men of God spake as they were moved by the Holy Ghost.

So the scriptures should not be interpreted through eisegesis, but by the inspiration of the Holy Ghost, which is the same power by which they were originally given.

Comment: Might "private interpretation" refer to the prophecy itself as if it was a "private interpretation" _of events_ rather than the "interpretation" of the prophecy?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I've ever heard the term "eisegesis" used in anything but a polemical tone, so I suspect you aren't going to have anyone telling you that it's a good practice.

That said, the exegetical approach that most Christians typically espouse (cf. Fee & Stuart *How to Read the Bible for All its Worth*), "The text can never mean what it never meant" has serious flaws. Hermeneutics are intrinsically tied to epistemology—and the truth of the matter is that we *cannot ever* know *for sure* what any text *meant*, and therefor have no way to verify whether we are in fact committing [that most grievous of sins] eisegesis.

Furthermore, while most moderately informed Christians try to pull meaning "out" of a text (hence "exegesis"), the NT authors and most early Christians had no such sensibility. This is why so many OT texts are re-appropriated as prophecies about Jesus. The *locus classicus* is Isa 7:14. Who is Isa 7:14 about? Hezekiah. What does the NT say? It's about Jesus. Or better: Isa 40:3 was re-appropriated by both early Christians (referring to John the Baptist), and also by the Qumran community as a reference to themselves.

My own personal worldview values very highly a historical–critical approach to the Bible. That said, if we say that an exegetical approach is the *only* faithful way of interpreting the Bible we exclude all those who interpreted the Bible for the first 1500 years of the Church. This is not acceptable in my opinion.

Comment: This is a first - having Isaiah 7:14 reference anyone other than Jesus: who else would be called "God with us"?

Comment: @warren,I don't even know how to respond to that. Read all of Isa 7 and explain to me how that is about Jesus.

Comment: Hear, hear!  This is a wonderful, well-balanced, and helpful answer.  One of the most popular hermeneutical methods used by Christian preachers (the Christological approach) is eisegesis _par excellence_.